# Shaders: packing 4 textures into a single RGBA - slower?

Tags: shaders, glsl, opengl-es2

I'm experiencing something really strange on an iOS mobile device. I have 4 textures, and after some profiling it seems, that doing four separate grayscale texture reads is faster, than reading the same textures from a single packed texture:

```
#ifdef COMBINED_METALLIC_ROUGHNESS_AO_EMISSION_TEXTURE
    fixed4 mraeTex = tex2D(_MetallicRoughnesAOEmissionTex, IN.uv_MainTex);

    fixed metallic = mraeTex.r;
    fixed roughness = mraeTex.g;
    fixed ambientOcclusion = mraeTex.b;
    fixed3 emission = mraeTex.a * albedo;
#else
    fixed metallic = tex2D(_MetallicTex, IN.uv_MainTex).r * _Metallic;
    fixed roughness = tex2D(_RoughnessTex, IN.uv_MainTex).r * _Roughness;
    fixed ambientOcclusion = tex2D(_AmbientOcclusionTex, IN.uv_MainTex).r;
    fixed3 emission = tex2D(_EmissionTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb;
#endif
```

It seems, that the second option is faster for some reason. Isn't a single texture read supposed to be faster, than doing 4 separate texture reads? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: I too am surprised and not sure of an explanation why it would be slower. If it were just equal speed I would respond that the shader compiler saw you only wanted the r component so optimized the texture read to grab only that. But slower? Not really sure.  If you don't get an answer here you might ask on the computer graphics stack exchange site.

Comment: I think I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251772/what-exactly-constitutes-swizzling-in-opengl-es-2-0-powervr-sgx-specifically   PowerVR says "Swizzling the components of lowp vectors is expensive and should be avoided."

Comment: Apparently .r etc is swizzling and is expensive on PowerVR platforms.

Comment: that makes sense, interesting!

Answer (score 2):

According to PowerVR "Swizzling the components of lowp vectors is expensive and should be avoided". Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251772/what-exactly-constitutes-swizzling-in-opengl-es-2-0-powervr-sgx-specifically